# Directed Adjacency Lists

Tags: graph, adjacency-list, directed-graph, adjacency-matrix

I have asked this question in a variety of ways, starting with:

> When you have an adjacency list, does order matter? Say I had the adjacency list {1, 2, 5} is that
> equivalent to {2, 1, 5}? Or does order signify something and therefore these two lists are not
> equivalent?

I received several answers including it only matters if the graph is directed and the order signifies something to do with the adjacent nodes arrangement clockwise..? I also was given the opinion that no it does not matter, however he'd prefer it be ordered regarding weights (if used) such as the way the internet is ordered - page ranking algorithm. I don't presume to paraphrase any of these responses accurately although I think I conveyed the gist. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Also, I have refined my question in a way that if answered, I think will give me the exact answer I am after:

> Suppose I have the adjacency matrix for a directed graph:
>
> 0 0 1 0
>
> 0 0 1 1
>
> 1 1 0 1
>
> 0 1 1 0
>
> I am told the equivalent adjacency lists are as follows and presume my teacher listed it this way
> intentionally rather than some arbitrary reordering - especially as seen in the last list:
>
> { 2 }
>
> { 2, 3 }
>
> { 0, 1, 3 }
>
> { 2, 1 }
>
> The last list is { 2, 1 }! What in the equivalent adjacency matrix alerts me that it should be
> { 2, 1 } rather than { 1, 2 }?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Typically, no, the order in adjacency list doesn't matter.**

... unless explicitly stated.

Implementation may have the list actually ordered for various reasons: as a consequence of how the graph is created, or because you want to process neighbors of a vertex in some order.
But conceptually, the order doesn't matter.

I believe that *no* is the answer in your case, `{2,1}` is the same as `{1,2}`. Perhaps your teacher wrote it wrong at first (like `{2,3}`) and didn't change the order after fixing it. Or he/she wanted you to go thinking whether the order does matter. Won't know for sure, unless you ask the teacher.

Answer (score 0):

The value of a node in an adjacency list is a set.  Sets are unordered. Therefore {1,2} is the same as {2,1}.